# Determine Parent Child

Tags: excel, vba

[image: ParentChild]

Hi All.

I've created VBA Macro in Excel to provide the Indent value in col B (from Alignment tab of the Format Cell screen) and trying to establish Parent/Child in Col C.  The output should match Col D, but having a hard time getting the logic in.  It has to look at Col B to build Parent/Child as Col A could be different values at times.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

```
Sub GetIndentLevels()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim indentLevel As Integer

' Set the worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Target") ' Change "Sheet1" to your sheet name

' Find the last row with data in column A
lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

' Loop through each row in column A
For i = 1 To lastRow
    ' Get the range for the current cell in column A
    Set rng = ws.Cells(i, "A")
    
    ' Get the indent level of the cell
    indentLevel = rng.indentLevel
    
    ' Write the indent level to column B
    ws.Cells(i, "B").Value = indentLevel
Next i
End Sub

Sub DetermineParentChild()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim currentRow As Long
Dim currentValue As Variant
Dim nextValue As Variant
Dim markParent As Boolean

' Set the worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Target")

' Find the last row in column A
lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

' Initialize the markParent variable
markParent = False

' Loop through each row in column A
For currentRow = 1 To lastRow
    ' Get the value of column B for the current row
    currentValue = ws.Cells(currentRow, 2).Value
    
    ' Check if the current value is numeric
    If IsNumeric(currentValue) Then
        ' Check if the next row exists and get its value
        If currentRow < lastRow Then
            ' Get the value of column B for the next row
            nextValue = ws.Cells(currentRow + 1, 2).Value
        Else
            ' If there is no next row, set nextValue to a default value
            nextValue = ""
        End If
        
        ' Check if the current value should be marked as "P" (Parent) or "C" (Child)
        If markParent Then
            ws.Cells(currentRow, 3).Value = "P"
        Else
            If nextValue = currentValue + 1 Then
                ws.Cells(currentRow, 3).Value = "P"
            Else
                ws.Cells(currentRow, 3).Value = "C"
            End If
        End If
        
        ' Update the markParent variable for the next iteration
        markParent = (nextValue <> currentValue + 1)
    Else
        ' If the current value is not numeric, mark it as "C" (Child)
        ws.Cells(currentRow, 3).Value = "C"
    End If
Next currentRow
End Sub
```

[image: also add if the current row's indentation level is less than previous row's indentation level, but the next row's indentation level is the same as current, then C.]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Use table formatting to insert textual data instead.

Comment: Please show column heading in your screenshot. What's your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Your code is fairly close to finish. You'll get the expected output by removing the logic of `markParent`.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub DetermineParentChild()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim currentRow As Long
    Dim currentValue As Variant
    Dim nextValue As Variant
    Dim markParent As Boolean
    ' Set the worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    ' Find the last row in column A
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    ' Initialize the markParent variable
    markParent = False
    ' Loop through each row in column A
    For currentRow = 2 To lastRow  ' ** start from row 2
        ' Get the value of column B for the current row
        currentValue = ws.Cells(currentRow, 2).Value
        ' Check if the current value is numeric
        If IsNumeric(currentValue) Then
            ' Check if the next row exists and get its value
            If currentRow < lastRow Then
                ' Get the value of column B for the next row
                nextValue = ws.Cells(currentRow + 1, 2).Value
            Else
                ' If there is no next row, set nextValue to a default value
                nextValue = ""
            End If
            ' Check if the current value should be marked as "P" (Parent) or "C" (Child)
            ' ***
            If nextValue = currentValue + 1 Then
                ws.Cells(currentRow, 3).Value = "P"
            Else
                ws.Cells(currentRow, 3).Value = "C"
            End If
            ' ***
        Else
            ' If the current value is not numeric, mark it as "C" (Child)
            ws.Cells(currentRow, 3).Value = "C"
        End If
    Next currentRow
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

### Parent-Child vs `Range.IndentLevel`

[image]

**The Calling Procedure (Example)**

```vb
Sub RunParentChild()

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Target")
    Dim rg As Range:
    Set rg = ws.Range("A1", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    
    Dim IndentLevels() As Long: IndentLevels = GetIndentLevels(rg)
        
    With rg.EntireRow
        .Columns("B").Value = IndentLevels ' not necessary
        .Columns("C").Value = GetIndentedParentChildFromColumn(rg, IndentLevels)
    End With

End Sub
```

**The Called (Helper) Procedures**

```vb
Function GetIndentLevels(rg As Range) As Long()
    
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = rg.Rows.Count
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = rg.Columns.Count
    
    Dim Data() As Long: ReDim Data(1 To rCount, 1 To cCount)
    
    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    
    For r = 1 To rCount
        For c = 1 To cCount
            Data(r, c) = rg.Cells(r, c).IndentLevel
        Next c
    Next r
    
    GetIndentLevels = Data

End Function
```

- One could shorten the following function by eliminating the `i` and `IsParent` variables, the whole `If r = rCount Then` statement, and the line before it. Then, instead of `If IsParent Then`, one could use the rather unreadable (in VBA `True = -1`)...

  ```
   If IndentLevels(r + 2 * (r = rCount) + 1, 1) > IndentLevels(r, 1) Then
  ```
- Even the following one-liner would work:

  ```
   cData(r, 1) = IIf(IndentLevels(r + 2 * (r = rCount) + 1, 1) > IndentLevels(r, 1), "P", "C")
  ```

  Both are not recommended!

```vb
Function GetIndentedParentChildFromColumn( _
    rg As Range, _
    IndentLevels() As Long, _
    Optional ColumnIndex As Long = 1) _
As Variant
    
    Dim cData As Variant: cData = GetRange(rg.Columns(ColumnIndex))
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = UBound(cData, 1)
    
    Dim r As Long, i As Long, IsFirstFound As Boolean, IsParent As Boolean
    
    For r = 1 To rCount
        If IsFirstFound Then
            i = IndentLevels(r, 1)
            If r = rCount Then
                IsParent = IndentLevels(r - 1, 1) > i
            Else
                IsParent = IndentLevels(r + 1, 1) > i
            End If
            If IsParent Then
                cData(r, 1) = "P"
                IsParent = False ' reset for the next iteration
            Else
                cData(r, 1) = "C"
            End If
        Else
            cData(r, 1) = "P"
            IsFirstFound = True
        End If
    Next r

    GetIndentedParentChildFromColumn = cData
    
End Function
```

```vb
Function GetRange(rg As Range) As Variant()
    If rg.Rows.Count + rg.Columns.Count = 2 Then
        ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = rg.Value: GetRange = Data
    Else
        GetRange = rg.Value
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: One thing to note, it has to only look at indent levels as SUB may be a different member name for other applications.  When I remove the SUB logic, it all works except for a few.  I'm trying to add another CASE statement that says "If the current row's indentation level is less than previous row's indentation level, but the next row's indentation level is the same as current, then C." but not having luck on the remainder.  I'll post my results in my original post.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've implemented the logic you mentioned and eliminated the `SUB` comparisons. It seems that in the data in column `E`, the value in `E20` is invalid i.e. it cannot be `P`. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: That's correct.  E20 should be C.  Many thanks!